# Best columnDef for this situation

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a request for the best solution to this AG-Grid situation. Currently using version 25.3.0 Enterprise.

Have a set of rows with values in each row representing school grades. We represent each grade numerically like this:

- -1 = Pre-K          display as: PK
- 0 = K              display as: K
- 1 = First grade    display as: 1
- 2 = Second grade   display as: 2
- ...
- 12 = Twelfth grade  display as: 12

I store the numeric value (code) as "grade_code" and the alpha value (name) as "grade_code_name", in each of the records.

My question is: what is the best columnDef configuration to handle:

- display of the alpha value
- sort on numeric value
- filter on alpha value
- row-grouping on numeric value (but still display alpha value in synthetic column)
- charting using alpha value as "keys"

Basically, handle everything that can be done with AG-Grid while maintaining ordering/grouping on numeric value, filtering on alpha value, while also ALWAYS displaying the alpha value.

I've tried multiple combos of valueGetters, valueFormatters, cellRenderers and have not been able to solve for all of the above simultaneously. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of `valueGetter` and `valueFormatter` to achieve your desired result. The gist of it is that you need to display the `grade_code_name` while the value behind it is the `grade_code`.

Try the following column definition:

```
{
    headerName: 'Grade',
    field: 'grade_code_name',
    sortable: true,
    filter: true,
    comparator: (valueA, valueB, nodeA, nodeB, isInverted) => {
      if (!nodeA || !nodeB) {
        return;
      }
      if (nodeA.data.grade_code == nodeB.data.grade_code) return 0;
      return nodeA.data.grade_code > nodeB.data.grade_code ? 1 : -1;
    },
    enableRowGroup: true,
    valueGetter: (params) => {
      if (!params.data) {
        return;
      }

      return params.data.grade_code;
    },
    valueFormatter: (params) => {
      if (!params.data) {
        return;
      }

      return params.data.grade_code_name;
    },
  },
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/1Zdvj51YNqQQq8yO).

Comment: Hi @Chris C if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.